# Inheriting VirtualizingStackPanel, InternalChildren.Count returns zero

Tags: c#, wpf, layout, virtualizingstackpanel

I implement some additional logic for elements arrangement.

I override MeasureOverride and ArrangeOverride. If I inherit from StackPanel everything works. What is not the case for VirtualizingStackPanel as a parent. Debug revealed that InternalChildren.Count returns zero as if no element's container has been generated yet. I definitely miss something for VSP. And I guess it is virtualizing. Can anyone help me with this?

P.S. Both variants of inheritance were tested for the ItemsControl.ItemsPanel